# Evaluating Given Integrals to Evaluate the Unknown Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Use the fact that $\int_{0}^{b}\frac{1}{1+ax}\,dx=\frac{1}{a}\ln(1+ab)$ to evaluate $\int_{0}^{b}\frac{x}{(1+ax)^2}\,dx$.

Besides eyeballing it and guessing what the answer *could be*, I don't know mucg else. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not integrate by parts?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Integrate by parts for which equation? And to solve for what exactly?

Comment: You want to evaluate $\int_0^b \frac{x}{(1+ax)^2}\,dx$ using the given fact, so let $u = x$ (which has a very simple derivative) and $dv = \frac{dx}{(1+ax)^2}$ (which has a very simple antiderivative) and see what you get!

Comment: Do you know "u-Substitution" or "the substitution method"?  (Parts isn't needed here.)

Answer (score 3):

[Feynman's trick](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf) again: since $\frac{x}{(1+ax)^2}=-\frac{d}{da}\frac{1}{1+ax}$, it follows that:

> $$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{b}\frac{x}{(1+ax)^2}\,dx = -\frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^{b}\frac{dx}{1+ax} &=& \color{red}{-\frac{d}{da}\left(\frac{1}{a}\cdot\log(1+ab)\right)}\\[0.2cm]&=&\color{blue}{\frac{\log(1+ab)}{a^2}-\frac{b}{a(1+ab)}}.\end{eqnarray*} $$